# How to zip the files in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to zip the text files programatically.

I have created text files at files `directory(context.getFilesDirectory())`, 
I want zip the text files and add the zipped file to the Intent object.

Please provide me a piece of code to how to zip the files in android.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a FOLDER in SDCard and you want to create a zip of it, then simply copy and paste this code in your project and it will give you a zip Folder. This code will create a zip of the folder which only contains files no nested folder should be inside. You can further modify for your self.

```
 String []s=new String[2]; //declare an array for storing the files i.e the path of your source files
  s[0]="/mnt/sdcard/Wallpaper/pic.jpg";    //Type the path of the files in here
  s[1]="/mnt/sdcard/Wallpaper/Final.pdf"; // path of the second file

  zip((s,"/mnt/sdcard/MyZipFolder.zip");    //call the zip function


 public void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) 
 { 
    private String[] _files= files;
    private String _zipFile= zipFile;  

try  { 
  BufferedInputStream origin = null; 
  FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile); 

  ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest)); 

  byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER]; 

  for(int i=0; i < _files.length; i++) { 
      Log.d("add:",_files[i]);
    Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]); 
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]); 
    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER); 
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1)); 
    out.putNextEntry(entry); 
    int count; 
    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) { 
      out.write(data, 0, count); 
    } 
    origin.close(); 
  } 

  out.close(); 
} catch(Exception e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

}

> Also add permissions in android-manifest.xml using this code

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, two invalid usages of keyword "private", and BUFFER is undefined.

Comment: @RenniePet But why it is running with me, huh

Comment: Can you tell me what should be ideal value of buffer variable?

Comment: @14bce109 yes ther is size for it, put BUFFER=1024 it will work, if could't then inbox me , I will help you

Comment: Good, but don't forget check is file path a directory

Comment: BUFFER = 1024 * 1024 // one Mega byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compress files with password you can take a look at [this library](https://github.com/ghost1372/Mzip-Android) you need to add this lines to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.ghost1372:Mzip-Android:0.4.0'
}
```

here is the code to zip files:

**Zip:**

```
ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
zipArchive.zip(targetPath,destinationPath,password);
```

//This Library is dead as it is not avaialable on github anymore

Comment: Don't use that library anyway. It is buggy. Sometime the zip creation is randomly bigger in size.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for zipping the files. You have to add all the file paths which you want to zip into the arrayList and send it as parameter to below function along with string name for zipfile you want.

```
 public String zipper(ArrayList<String> allFiles, String zipFileName) throws IOException
    {
        timeStampOfZipFile =new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        App.mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
        zippath = App.mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + zipFileName+ timeStampOfZipFile +  ".zip";
        try
        {
            if (new File(zippath).exists())
            {
                new File(zippath).delete();
            }
            //new File(zipFileName).delete(); // Delete if exists
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zippath);
            ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
            zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
            zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
            zipParameters.setPassword("Reset");

            if (allFiles.size() > 0)
            {
                for (String fileName : allFiles)
                {
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    zipFile.addFile(file, zipParameters);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (ZipException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return zippath;
    }
```

Here `App.mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();` 
where mediaStorage is static final string in my `App.class`

```
public static final File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "yourAppFoler");
```

creates directory where the zip file will be saved. Result of function returns zip file path which can be used to attach to multipart entity for sending it to server(if you wish).

Requires run time permission for API>=marshmellow

```
  <!-- == External Storage == -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This code doesn't use `java.util.zip.ZipFile` that can only **read** a ZIP file. [`net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile`](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j) has been used instead.